# Converting a cURL command to HTTR in R

Tags: r, httr

I have a cURL command that I would like to convert to R using the `httr` package. The cURL command looks something like this (I obviously can't post the full scope of it, given certain confidentiality restrictions):

```
curl --request POST \
     --url https://api.cfb.com/v1/players/110960703/stats \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     --header 'Authorization: Basic ThisIsWhereTheAPIKeyGoes==' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '
{
     "statsContext": {
          "statsId": "1"
     },
     "responses": [
          {
                    "type": "ReceiverStats",
                    "QuestionId": "466069",
                    "ResponseId": "1898226"
          }
     ]
}
'
```

I would like to convert it to an HTTR script that looks like this:

```
ExportIdAPI <- POST(
  'https://api.cfb.com/v1/players/110960703/stats',
  accept_json(),                       
  content_type_json(),                  
  add_headers(Authorization = Basic ThisIsWhereTheAPIKeyGoes==),  
  encode = "json",
  body=list(statsId = 1,
            QuestionId = 466069,
            ResponseId = 1898226))
```

The problem is, this script does not work. What does work is this script:

```
ExportIdAPI <- POST(
      'https://api.cfb.com/v1/players/110960703/stats',
      accept_json(),                       
      content_type_json(),                  
      add_headers(Authorization = Basic ThisIsWhereTheAPIKeyGoes==),  
      encode = "json",
      body=list(statsId = 1))
```

Based on how the original curl request is structured, am I just not storing it right in the `body=list` statement?

EDIT: I should note that this script runs perfectly fine. I just don't want it to be structured that way and I would like it to better reflect the format I'm trying to achieve from above.

```
headers = c(
  `Accept` = 'application/json',
  `Authorization` = 'Basic ThisIsWhereTheAPIKeyGoes==',
  `Content-Type` = 'application/json'
)

data = ' { "statsContext": { "statsId": "1" }, "responses": [ { "type": "SurveyResponse", "QuestionId": "466069", "ResponseId": "1898226" } ] } '

res <- httr::POST(url = 'https://api.cfb.com/v1/players/110960703/stats', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data)
```

EDIT 2: Based on MrFlick's response, I tried running:

```
ExportIdAPI <- POST(
  'https://api.cfb.com/v1/players/110960703/stats',
  accept_json(),                       
  content_type_json(),                  
  add_headers(Authorization = Basic ThisIsWhereTheAPIKeyGoes==),  
  encode = "json",
  data = list(statsContext = list(statsId = 1), responses= list(list(type="SurveyResponse", QuestionId="466069", ResponseId="1898226")))
)
```

But I'm met with the following error:

```
Response [https://api.cfb.com/v1/players/110960703/stats]
  Date: 2021-08-26 20:58
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 144 B
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": "INVALID_PARAMETER",
      "text": "The body of the request is null or cannot be parsed."
    }
  ]
```

Comment: @MrFlick see the edit I just made. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the response. I tried putting in what you wrote above, but I'm still getting an error though. Please see the edit.

Comment: @MrFlick Just following up

Comment: The `POST()` request should use `POST(body=data)` from my example, or use `POST(body=list(...))` There is no `POST(data=)` parameter. I've added a complete answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The `httr` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.2/topics/POST) for the POST function provides an example for how to post a json.

In your case, you could really just copy the json of the cURL command to the body parameter of the POST function:

```kotlin
ExportIdAPI <- POST(
     'https://api.cfb.com/v1/players/110960703/stats',
     accept_json(),                       
     content_type_json(),                  
     add_headers(Authorization = 'Basic ThisIsWhereTheAPIKeyGoes=='),
     body = '
{
     "statsContext": {
       "statsId": "1"
     },
     "responses": [
          {
                    "type": "ReceiverStats",
                    "QuestionId": "466069",
                    "ResponseId": "1898226"
          }
     ]
}', encode = "raw")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `ROST()` request format the JSON for you. As a general rule named lists are turned into JSON objects `{}` and unnamed list become arrays `[]`. You can do

```
POST(
  'https://api.cfb.com/v1/players/110960703/stats',
  accept_json(),                       
  content_type_json(),                  
  add_headers(Authorization = "Basic ThisIsWhereTheAPIKeyGoes=="),  
  encode = "json",
  body = list(
    statsContext = list(
       statsId = 1
    ), 
    responses= list(
       list(
         type="SurveyResponse", 
         QuestionId="466069", 
         ResponseId="1898226"
       )
     )
   )
)
```